# Base electric heater safety/precaution

Tags: heater, electric-heat

I have a base heater that is installed in a wall (dry wall).
I noticed that after a while the wall right above the heater gets very hot to the touch. My concern is that this could be a fire hazard.

Wondering if I should add some kind of ceramic covering for the wall. A ceramic wall paper would be ideal. The idea is to keep the drywall, paint, and wood/insulation behind it from bursting into flames.

Any ideas?

PS - Note that the previous owner had installed the base heater upside-down! :(

Comment: What type of heater? Hot water? Electric? On the surface or recessed?

Comment: "Hot to the touch" could mean 140 degrees F (lower than the air temperature from a gas furnace). Fire hazards occur at over 400 degrees. What range of values are we talking about here?

Comment: Well, if i place my hand on the hottest spot on the wall, it would be a few seconds before it becomes unbearable. The temperature at the time i tested this was probably just hot enough to make the small room comfortable.